# All connections are refused from Cassandra on WSL2 ubuntu 22.04 in Windows 11

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cassandra

I install cassandra 4 on wsl2 ubuntu 22.04 on windows 11. Belows are the installation process.

```
$ sudo apt update -y
$ sudo apt upgrade -y
$ sudo apt install apt-transport-https gnupg2 -y
$ echo "deb https://debian.cassandra.apache.org 41x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
$ curl https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install cassandra -y
$ sudo systemctl status cassandra  --> service is active
```

But these `cqlsh`, `nodetool` commands throws the connection refused errors.

```
$ cqlsh

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})



$ nodetool status

nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'
```

So I modify the `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` file.

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
listen_address: localhost
broadcast_address: 1.2.3.4
```

But the connections are still refused. Belows are the error logs.

```
[1709282364953] INFO  (ls): Connection instance created for Cassandra Connection.
    ns: "conn-manager"
[1709282364970] ERROR (ls): Connecting error: {"code":-1,"data":{"driver":"Cassandra","driverOptions":{}},"name":"NoHostAvailableError"}
    ns: "conn-manager"
[1709282364971] ERROR (ls): Open connection error
    ns: "conn-manager"
[1709282364971] ERROR (ext): ERROR: Error opening connection All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 127.0.0.1:9042: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9042
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9042
}. See innerErrors., {"code":-1,"data":{"driver":"Cassandra","driverOptions":{}}}
    ns: "error-handler"
```

How can I open the port 9042 and execute `cqlsh` command on WSL2 ubuntu? I already open those port with ufw command. Any reply will be thanksful.

Comment: I would start with `s/listen_address: localhost/listen_address: 0.0.0.0/`

Comment: As you know, listen_address is cluster listening address, so setting 0.0.0.0 is totally incorrect.

Comment: I recommended 0.0.0.0 so that it wil listen on all interfaces. Localhost inside and outside of WSL is a little different